# How do I create a Shidoku grid?

Tags: tables, arrays

I can't figure out how to create a Shidoku grid using LaTeX.  In other words, I am trying to have a 4x4 grid with a bold line separating the 2x2 subsquares.  I have the `sudoku` package but it won't work when I try to decrease the number of rows and columns.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit:  I am using the following document classes:

```
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{sudoku}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a possible solution using a `tabular`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{P}{%
>{\rule[-0.6cm]{0pt}{1.5cm}\centering$}p{1cm}<{$}}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabular}{!{\vrule width 2pt}P|P!{\vrule width 2pt}P|P!{\vrule width 2pt}}
\noalign{\hrule height 2pt}
a & b & c & d \tabularnewline
\hline
a & b & c & d \tabularnewline
\noalign{\hrule height 2pt}
a & b & c & d \tabularnewline
\hline
a & b & c & d \tabularnewline
\noalign{\hrule height 2pt}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And a solution using TikZ:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% the matrix
\matrix [matrix of math nodes, nodes in empty cells,
     nodes={align=center},
    text width=1cm,text depth=0.4cm,text height=0.6cm] 
(shi)
{
a & b & c & d \\
a & b & c & d \\
a & b & c & d \\
a & b & c & d \\
};

% vertical rules
\foreach \i in {1,3}
  \draw (shi-1-\i.north east) -- (shi-4-\i.south east);
\foreach \i in {1,3}
  \draw[line width=2pt] (shi-1-\i.north west) -- (shi-4-\i.south west);
\draw[line width=2pt] (shi-1-4.north east) -- (shi-4-4.south east);

% horizontal rules
\foreach \i in {2,4}
  \draw (shi-\i-1.north west) -- (shi-\i-4.north east);
\foreach \i in {2,4}
  \draw[line width=2pt] (shi-\i-1.south west) -- (shi-\i-4.south east);
\draw[line width=2pt] (shi-1-1.north west) -- (shi-1-4.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And here's my first approach using a simpe `tabular` but now I've added the necessary font adjustments and defined an environment to simplify the writing; now a Shidoku is produce simply by something like:

```
\begin{shidoku}
\Srow{2}{5}{}{}
\Srow{}{1}{}{}
\Srow{4}{}{7}{}
\Srow{}{}{5}{2}
\end{shidoku}
```

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sudoku}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{P}{%
>{\rule[-6pt]{0pt}{30pt}\centering\Huge\sffamily}p{19pt}}

\newcommand\TPLine{\noalign{\hrule height 2pt}}

\newcounter{shrow}
\newenvironment{shidoku}
  {\setcounter{shrow}{0}\begin{center}\begin{tabular}{!{\vrule width 2pt}P|P!{\vrule width 2pt}P|P!{\vrule width 2pt}}}
  {\end{tabular}\end{center}}

\newcommand\Srow[4]{%
  \ifnum\value{shrow}=0 \TPLine\fi\stepcounter{shrow}%
  #1 & #2 & #3 & #4\tabularnewline
  \ifnum\value{shrow}=2 \TPLine\else\ifnum\value{shrow}=4 \TPLine\else\hline\fi\fi}

\begin{document}

\begin{shidoku}
\Srow{2}{5}{}{}
\Srow{}{1}{}{}
\Srow{4}{}{7}{}
\Srow{}{}{5}{2}
\end{shidoku}

\begin{sudoku}
| | | | | | | | | |.
| | | | | | | | | |.
| | | | | | | | | |.
| | | | | | | | | |.
| | | | | | | | | |.
| | | | | | | | | |.
| | | | | | | | | |.
| | | | | | | | | |.
| | | | | | | | | |.
\end{sudoku}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your speedy reply!  Unfortunately, when I use that formula, I get ! Use of \@array doesn't match its definition.

Comment: @KatherineM.: when you use what formula?

Comment: The first one,


\newcolumntype{P}{%
>{\rule[-0.6cm]{0pt}{1.5cm}\centering$}p{1cm}<{$}}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabular}{!{\vrule width 2pt}P|P!{\vrule width 2pt}P|P!{\vrule width 2pt}}
\noalign{\hrule height 2pt}
a & b & c & d \tabularnewline
\hline
a & b & c & d \tabularnewline
\noalign{\hrule height 2pt}
a & b & c & d \tabularnewline
\hline
a & b & c & d \tabularnewline
\noalign{\hrule height 2pt}
\end{tabular}

\end{document

Comment: @KatherineM. which document class are you using? You didn't include that information in your previous comment. It would be a good idea if you add to your original question a minimal complete example of the code that is not working for you.

Comment: @KatherineM.: with that document class and packages, my code works OK; however, I believe I recall that there were some problems between `array` and `ltxdoc` in old versions. Which version of `ltxdoc` are you using?

Comment: @KatherineM. now that I see your edit, you are loading the `array` package (as in my example), aren't you?

Comment: I'm not sure which version of ltxdoc it is, how would I figure that out? I am using the array package, it was just in a different location.  I copied the header information from a sudoku paper a while ago.

Comment: @KatherineM. So you can use a different document class? If that is so, then change `\documentclass{ltxdoc}` to `\documentclass{article}` and process my example code. If you really need to use ltxdoc, then let me know and I will try to detect the problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2942/discussion-between-gonzalo-medina-and-katherine-m)

Comment: @KatherineM. I've now added a new version of the code with the font size and family adjustments.

Answer (score 17):

You *don't* need to modify `sudoku.sty`, just to use its infrastructure: we can use the macros as modified by Harish Kumar, but changing their names. In this way you can input both sudoku and shidoku puzzles using a similar syntax.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sudoku}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\@shidoku@grid{
  \linethickness{\sudokuthinline}%
  \multiput(0,0)(1,0){5}{\line(0,1){4}}%
  \multiput(0,0)(0,1){5}{\line(1,0){4}}
  \linethickness{\sudokuthickline}%
  \multiput(0,0)(2,0){2}{\line(0,1){4}}%
  \multiput(0,0)(0,2){2}{\line(1,0){4}}
  \linethickness{0.5\sudokuthickline}%
  \put(0,0){\framebox(0,0){}}%
  \put(4,0){\framebox(0,0){}}%
  \put(0,4){\framebox(4,0){}}%
  \put(4,0){\framebox(0,4){}}
}
\newenvironment{shidoku-block}{%
        \catcode`\|=\active
        \@sudoku@activate
        \setcounter{@sudoku@col}{-1}%
        \setcounter{@sudoku@row}{3}%
        \setlength\unitlength{.111111\sudokusize}%
        \begin{picture}(4,4)%
        \@shidoku@grid\@shidoku@grab@arguments
        }{\end{picture}}

\def\@shidoku@grab@arguments#1.#2.#3.#4.{\scantokens{#1.#2.#3.#4.}}
\newenvironment{shidoku}{%
        \begin{center}%
        \begin{shidoku-block}}{\end{shidoku-block}\end{center}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{shidoku}
|2|5| | |.
| |1| | |.
|4| |7| |.
| | |5|2|.
\end{shidoku}

\begin{sudoku}
| | | | | | | | | |.
| | | | | | | | | |.
| | | | | | | | | |.
| | | | | | | | | |.
| | | | | | | | | |.
| | | | | | | | | |.
| | | | | | | | | |.
| | | | | | | | | |.
| | | | | | | | | |.
\end{sudoku}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @HarishKumar I've borrowed your nice code, of course.

Answer (score 14):

I have modified the `sudoku.sty` for you and here are the contents of the 4x4 `sudoku44.sty` file. Save the contents below in the name `sudoku44.sty` and keep it in the same directory as your `.tex` file. (Alternatively put the file in `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\sudoku\` and run a `refresh file name data base` if on windows.)

```
%%
%% This is file `sudoku44.sty'.
%%
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1999/12/01]
\ProvidesPackage{sudoku}
 [2006/03/25 v1.0.1 Sudoku grid]
\newcounter{@sudoku@row}
\newcounter{@sudoku@col}
\newcommand*\@sudoku@separator[1]{%
        \stepcounter{@sudoku@col}%
        \ifx#1\@sudoku@separator
                \expandafter#1%
        \else
                \ifx.#1%
                        \setcounter{@sudoku@col}{-1}%
                        \addtocounter{@sudoku@row}{-1}%
                \else
                        \put(\value{@sudoku@col},\value{@sudoku@row})%
                        {\makebox(1,1){\sudokuformat{#1}}}%
                \fi
        \fi
}
\begingroup
        \catcode`\|=\active
        \gdef\@sudoku@activate{\let|=\@sudoku@separator}
\endgroup
\newcommand*\@sudoku@grid{
        \linethickness{\sudokuthinline}%
        \multiput(0,0)(1,0){5}{\line(0,1){4}}%
        \multiput(0,0)(0,1){5}{\line(1,0){4}}
        \linethickness{\sudokuthickline}%
        \multiput(0,0)(2,0){2}{\line(0,1){4}}%
        \multiput(0,0)(0,2){2}{\line(1,0){4}}
        \linethickness{0.5\sudokuthickline}%
        \put(0,0){\framebox(0,0){}}%
        \put(4,0){\framebox(0,0){}}%
        \put(0,4){\framebox(4,0){}}%
        \put(4,0){\framebox(0,4){}}
}
\newcommand*\sudokuformat[1]{\Huge\sffamily#1}
\newdimen\sudokusize
\setlength\sudokusize{10cm}
\newdimen\sudokuthinline
\setlength\sudokuthinline{0.4pt}
\newdimen\sudokuthickline
\setlength\sudokuthickline{2pt}
\newenvironment{sudoku-block}{%
        \catcode`\|=\active
        \@sudoku@activate
        \setcounter{@sudoku@col}{-1}%
        \setcounter{@sudoku@row}{3}%
        \setlength\unitlength{.111111\sudokusize}%
        \begin{picture}(4,4)%
        \@sudoku@grid\@sudoku@grab@arguments
        }{\end{picture}}
 \begingroup
   \@ifundefined{eTeXversion}{\endgroup
     \def\@sudoku@grab@arguments#1{%
       \ifx#1\@sudoku@separator
         \expandafter#1%
       \else
          \PackageError{sudoku}{%
            Sudoku puzzles are not allowed in the arguments\MessageBreak
            of other commands}{%
            Either fix this in your source (possibly using the `lrbox'
            environment) or use an eTeX based LaTeX format}
        \fi
     }%
   }{\endgroup
     \def\@sudoku@grab@arguments#1.#2.#3.#4.{%
       \scantokens{#1.#2.#3.#4.}}%
   }
\newenvironment{sudoku}{%
        \begin{center}%
        \begin{sudoku-block}}{\end{sudoku-block}\end{center}}
\endinput
%%
%% End of file `sudoku44.sty'.
```

Now your main `.tex` file (say mysudoku.tex) will be like this:

```
%-------------sudoku--------------------------------
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sudoku44}
%---------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\begin{sudoku}
|2|5| | |.
| |1| | |.
|4| |7| |.
| | |5|2|.
\end{sudoku}
%---------------------------------------------------
\end{document}
%---------------------------------------------------
```

After compiling (with pdflatex, my preference), we get

[image]

**NOTE:** Do not erase or modify the original `sudoku.sty` file. Save the new file with a name `sudoku44.sty`. Then you can use both the files like

```
\usepackage{sudoku}
```

or

```
\usepackage{sudoku44}
```

But you can not use both the packages in the same `mysudoku.tex` file as they clash.

Comment: Thanks for your help, do you know if modifying the sudoku.sty file means that I won't be able to input sudoku files?

Comment: @KatherineM. You should not tamper the original `sudoku.sty` file. Leave it to itself. Copy the contents given above in a different file and name it `sudoku44.sty` (say). Then you can use the original `9x9` sudoku also.

Comment: I am very new to LaTeX and though you have taken the time to modify the code, I have no idea what to do with that.

Comment: @KatherineM. copy the contents of sudoku44 (the first code block) and paste in your editor. Save it as `sudoku44.sty`. Place this file in the same folder as your main `mysudoku.tex` (which I mentioned in the answer) that contains the second code block above. Compile `mysudoku.tex`. you are done -:)